# Sitecore Rendering, how to get rendering definition item?

Tags: c#, rendering, sitecore

We are using a hybrid razor engine to create components in Sitecore.
I need to get the rendering definition id, but i am not able to get it.
This is our `baseComponent` class that inherits from `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl`

```
protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  string razorpath = RazorPath;
  Model = GetViewModel();
  var itemId = ID; //renderingID || getitem() also not working

  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(itemId);
  Guid itemGuid;
  if (Guid.TryParse(itemId, out itemGuid))
  {
    var webControl = ContentStore.GetItem<WebControl>(itemId);
    if (webControl != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(webControl.View))
      razorpath = webControl.View.Replace("/WebControls", "");
  }

  var renderedContent = TemplateExpander.ExpandTemplate(razorpath, Model);

  output.Write(renderedContent);
}
```

Comment: Try `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.RenderingItem`

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.Page.Renderings`? (not sure I understand what you're after though)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're after, but since you're inheriting from Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl, it might be something like this you're after:

```
        var p = Parent as Sublayout;
        var rId = p.RenderingID;
```